# NSMutableArray (addObject) not working inside if statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have this code :

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i <[titleNews count]; ++i) {
    TFHppleElement *someText =[titleNews objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *result = [someText content];

    [arr addObject:result];
    if ([[arr objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:@"-- : --"]) {
        [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"x"];
        [arr addObject:@"/"];

    }

    NSLog(@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

the (replaceObjectAtIndex: withObject:) work fine but the (addObject)method not working

Comment: How can you tell it's not working?  Did you dump the entire array?

Comment: @ Daniel ,no i want to add the (/) object after the (x) in the array

Comment: Add an `NSLog(@"%@", arr);` after the closing `}` of your loop, to see what's in the array where.  You'll be surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're presuming that the "result" that you add to the array will always be at index i.  But the first time that you fall into your "if" body, you'll add an i+1 element ("/") and from then on everything will be off by one.

Comment: thanks daniel but i am new to iphone programing .so how i can solve this problem

Comment: You may be new to iPhone programming, but it's a simple general programming problem, not at all unique to iPhone.  The NSMutableArray spec lists dozens of methods that may (or may not) help.  Read them, think through what you're doing, and do some real programming, vs just modifying what you've already seen.